# Primary Key Value Not Incrementing Correctly

Tags: django, postgresql, auto-increment

I have a django model that started to have its ids increment strangely.

The postgres definition of the column (generated from Django Model):

```
id | integer | not null default nextval('billing_invoice_id_seq'::regclass)

tpg=> SELECT MAX(id) FROM billing_invoice;
  max  
-------
 16260
```

Then I created a new record through the django admin:

```
tpg=> SELECT MAX(id) FROM billing_invoice;
  max  
-------
 17223

tpg=> SELECT nextval('billing_invoice_id_seq');
 nextval 
---------
   17224
```

Then I created a new record which skipped the 17224 value and was inserted with primary key of 17225:

```
tpg=> SELECT nextval('billing_invoice_id_seq');
 nextval 
---------
   17226
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring? The application doesn't care at this point because the ids are still incrementing, but over the last couple new objects the PKs have skipped from 427 -> 4357 in one insert and then to 8378 in 2 objects it jumped to 97xx then in 3 objects it jumped to 14k.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Serial columns taking their default from sequences are ***never*** guaranteed to be *gapless*. They are guaranteed to be *unique* and *ascending* (as defined) and *safe for concurrent use*.
If a transaction that has drawn a number from the sequence is rolled back, the number is burnt and not used again ... [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

> Note: Because `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` are implemented using
>   sequences, there may be "holes" or gaps in the sequence of values
>   which appears in the column, even if no rows are ever deleted. A value
>   allocated from the sequence is still "used up" even if a row
>   containing that value is never successfully inserted into the table
>   column. This may happen, for example, if the inserting transaction rolls back.
>   See `nextval()` in [Section 9.16](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html) for details.

If you see large gaps like `427 -> 4357`, then this indicates a serious problem. Either some other column (or any process) is drawing from the same sequence, or you have a problem with your application logic, somehow burning a lot of serial IDs.

Typical candidates are loops gone wrong or transactions that never got committed.