# Sequential increment skipping numbers

Tags: node.js, postgresql, macos, express, sequence

```
ID | info
---------
1  | xxx
2  | xxx
4  | xxx
```

I have a setup similar to this in PostgreSQL. (I'm using a *mac* running *Mojave* if that makes a difference).

I have a few more columns but the issue is the `ID` column. This was set to be sequential, so using Express I insert into the DB.

Problem is, it increments the `ID` on every insert even failing inserts. `info` is  defined `unique`, so trying to insert an existing `info` returns an error. But `ID` is still incremented.

For example, if I insert 2 rows, I have `id 1` & `id 2`. Then another one that fails with a unique violation. The the next successful insert gets `id = 4`, skipping `id = 3`.

Can I set up Postgres so it doesn't increment on failed inserts?

Comment: You might provide your Postgres version and the actual INSERT statement you use. And what's the load on your database? Concurrent write access or not?

Comment: Sequences (not only in postgresql) are designed to allow multiple users insert unique values at the same time (e.g. user #1 starts a transaction, inserts data and then does something else, then user #2 starts a transactions, inserts data and commits, and finally user #1 commits). There would be little use for them to develop something like this as a simple DELETE would break everything down.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`serial`  columns, or `IDENTITY` in Postgres 10 or later, draw numbers from a `SEQUENCE` and gaps are to be expected. Their job is to make concurrent write access possible with unique numbers - *not* necessarily gap-less numbers.

If you **don't actually have concurrent write access**, there are simple ways to achieve (mostly) gap-less numbers. Like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (info) 
SELECT 'xxx'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM tbl WHERE info = 'xxx');
```

That doesn't burn a serial ID from the `SEQUENCE` because a duplicate insert is skipped. (The `INSERT` might still fail for any other reason - and burn a serial number. You *could* reset the `SEQUENCE` in such a case:

- [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/23390399#23390399)

While inserting multiple rows in a single statement, you also have to rule out duplicates *within* the inserted set. Example code:

- [Return data from subselect used in INSERT in a Common Table Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202078/return-data-from-subselect-used-in-insert-in-a-common-table-expression/47203565#47203565)

But **if you do have concurrent writes**, none of the above works reliably, on principle. You better learn to accept gaps in the IDs. You can always have a query with `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id)` to generate gap-less numbers after the fact. However, the numbers are still arbitrary to a degree. Smaller numbers were not necessarily committed earlier. There are exceptions under concurrent write load. Related:

- [Primary Key Value Not Incrementing Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207845/primary-key-value-not-incrementing-correctly/25207912#25207912)
- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key/24918964#24918964)
- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Or consider a UUID instead (dat type `uuid`) and avoid the inherent problem of duplicates with random values in a *huge* key space. Not at all *serial*, though:

- [Generating a UUID in Postgres for Insert statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement)

Comment: You're right, at that Gaps don't matter in my case (or most cases for that matter I suppose). Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but in my case the amount of burned ids is something to worry in the long run. Reading your (many) SO answers about this specific topic got me to understand it better, but unfortunately none of them seems to be aplicable in my case (other than switching to uuid, which I would like to avoid if possible). What do you think of creating triggers to `SELECT setval('seq', MAX(id))`, or having it as CTE in the query for "resetting" the sequence?

Comment: @JesusJimenez: Use a `bigserial` or `bigint IDENTITY` then. Are you aware of the gigantic number space of a `bigint` column? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33838373/939860. Resetting the sequence in a trigger or otherwise is much more convoluted and expensive, and bound to fail under concurrent write load.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I wasn't aware of the time that could take to run out of ids. Although the gap feels like bad implementation to me, "expensive" is other word to avoid. So as long as I don't look at the gaps, I think there's no problem then.